# Please help me understand this bundler conflict in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I really cannot see the problem with the below - sprockets v 3.7.2 is installed, and the dependencies say it should be >= 2.8 and < 4.0 (it is), and >= 3.0.0 (it is)

How is this not working?  How is 3.7.2 not >= 3.0.0 and < 4.0 ?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sprockets

    recurring_select was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
      sass-rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8)

    recurring_select was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
        sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
          sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ gem list sprockets

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sprockets (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1, 2.3.3)
```

Comment: What's `bundle list sprockets` return?

Comment: It seems the problem is caused by having two version of the sprockets-rails gem, have you tried removing one of them? I think the command is `bundle uninstall sprockets-rails` or maybe `gem uninstall sprockets-rails`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the bundle errors, I want to suggest you to do these things.

Use the rbenv or rvm.

Install the clean ruby using rbenv or rvm.
Then use commands like "rbenv local 2.2.5" or "rvm use 2.2.5"

> (Uninstall the messed up version if you already have one, uninstalling
>   the ruby will remove all the gems along with it).

Use the fresh version of ruby and do "bundle install"

Bundle will download the appropriate versions for all the gems.